# qdraw doesn't plot using wxmaxima

Tags: macos, maxima

I've been working thru some examples for Maxima. I use wxmaxima on my imac and it usually works well. Recently I ran some examples which used qdraw to make plots. For some reason, qdraw does not work with wxmaxima. It does not generate an error message or any output at all. If I run Maxima from a terminal then qdraw works fine. I can plot in wxmaxima using plot2d or wxplot2d. Just not with qdraw. I'm using Maxima 5.38 and wxmaxima 16.04.0 on my iMac running Sierra.